# How to implement firebase data delete function?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-realtime-database

This chat app has 6 types of messages (text-mine, text-friend/Img-mine,Img-friend/Audio-mine,Audio-friend) This method is confusing me to implement message delete function in the app. I tried onItemLongClick and swipe, but I couldn't succeed. And how to get the firebase message IDs to delete?

How to Implement delete button or swipe function on this List Message Adapter?

[image]

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.bphvcg.apho.Fragments.ImageMessageFragment;
import com.bphvcg.apho.Models.Message;
import com.bphvcg.apho.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class RecyclerListMessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerListMessageAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
    private List<Message> listMessages;
    private int rMessageMine, rMessageFriend, rImageMessageMine, rImageMessageFriend, rAudioMessageMine, rAudioMessageFriend;
    Context context;
    private String mFileName = "";
    private  MediaPlayer mPlayer=null;
    private String currentAudio = "";
    public static ImageButton btnCurrentPlay = null;
    public static MediaPlayer getCurrentMedia = null;

    private StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    boolean isFinish = false; // kiểm tra audio đã hết chưa

    public RecyclerListMessageAdapter(List<Message> listMessages, Context context, int rMessageMine, int rMessageFriend,
                                      int rImageMessageMine, int rImageMessageFriend, int rAudioMessageMine, int rAudioMesageFriend) {
        this.listMessages = listMessages;
        this.rMessageMine = rMessageMine; // layout tin nhắn của bản thân
        this.rMessageFriend = rMessageFriend; // layout tin nhắn của bạn
        this.rImageMessageMine = rImageMessageMine; // layout tin nhắn ảnh của bản thân
        this.rImageMessageFriend = rImageMessageFriend; // layout tin nhắn ảnh của bạn
        this.rAudioMessageMine = rAudioMessageMine;
        this.rAudioMessageFriend = rAudioMesageFriend;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewMessageMine, textViewMessageTimeMine, textViewMessageFriend, textViewMessageTimeFriend;
        TextView imageViewMessageMineTime, imageViewMessageFriendTime;
        ImageView imageViewMessageMine, imageViewMessageFriend;
        CircleImageView avatarSeen, avatarSeenImage, avatarSeenAudio;

        ImageButton btnPlayAudioMessageMine, btnPlayAudioMessageFriend;
        TextView textViewMessageTimeAudioMine, textViewMessageTimeAudioFriend;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewMessageMine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageMine);
            textViewMessageTimeMine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageTimeMine);
            textViewMessageFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageFriend);
            textViewMessageTimeFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageTimeFriend);

            imageViewMessageMine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMessageMine);
            imageViewMessageFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMessageFriend);
            imageViewMessageMineTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMessageTimeMine);
            imageViewMessageFriendTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMessageTimeFriend);

            btnPlayAudioMessageMine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayAudioMessageMine);
            btnPlayAudioMessageFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayAudioMessageFriend);

            textViewMessageTimeAudioMine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAudioMessageTimeMine);
            textViewMessageTimeAudioFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAudioMessageTimeFriend);

            avatarSeen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatarSeen);
            avatarSeenImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatarSeenImage);
            avatarSeenAudio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatarSeenAudio);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (listMessages.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        else if (listMessages.get(position).getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                && !listMessages.get(position).isImage() && !listMessages.get(position).isAudio()) // The message itself is text
            return 1;
        else if (!listMessages.get(position).getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                && !listMessages.get(position).isImage() && !listMessages.get(position).isAudio()) // Your message is text
            return 2;
        else if (listMessages.get(position).getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                && listMessages.get(position).isImage()) // Your own message is a picture
            return 3;
        else if (!listMessages.get(position).getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                && listMessages.get(position).isImage()) //Your message is photo
            return 4;
        else if (listMessages.get(position).getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                && listMessages.get(position).isAudio()) { // Your message is audio
            return 5;
        } else if (!listMessages.get(position).getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                && listMessages.get(position).isAudio()) { // Your message is audio news
            return 6;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerListMessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create your own text message view
        View viewMessageMine = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rMessageMine, parent, false);
        // Create your text message view
        View viewMessageFriend = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rMessageFriend, parent, false);
        // Create your own picture message view
        View viewImageMessageMine = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rImageMessageMine, parent, false);
        // Create your picture message view
        View viewImageMessageFriend = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rImageMessageFriend, parent, false);

        View viewAudioMessageMine = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rAudioMessageMine, parent, false);

        View viewAudioMessageFriend = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rAudioMessageFriend, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;


        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                viewHolder = null;
                break;
            case 1:
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(viewMessageMine);
                break;
            case 2:
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(viewMessageFriend);
                break;
            case 3:
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(viewImageMessageMine);
                break;
            case 4:
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(viewImageMessageFriend);
                break;
            case 5:
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(viewAudioMessageMine);
                break;
            case 6:
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(viewAudioMessageFriend);
                break;

        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerListMessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (listMessages.isEmpty()) {
            //holder.textViewMessageNow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            final Message msg = listMessages.get(position);
            if (msg.getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && !msg.isImage() && !msg.isAudio()) {
                holder.textViewMessageMine.setText(msg.getContent());
                holder.textViewMessageTimeMine.setText(msg.getTimeMessage().substring(11, 16));
            } else if (!msg.getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && !msg.isImage() && !msg.isAudio()) {
                holder.textViewMessageFriend.setText(msg.getContent());
                holder.textViewMessageTimeFriend.setText(msg.getTimeMessage().substring(11, 16));
            } else if (msg.getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && msg.isImage()) {
                getImageStorage(holder.imageViewMessageMine, msg.getUidSender(), msg.getUidReceiver(), msg.getContent());
                holder.imageViewMessageMineTime.setText(msg.getTimeMessage().substring(11, 16));
                final String nameImage = msg.getContent();
                holder.imageViewMessageMine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
                        ImageMessageFragment imageMessageFragment = ImageMessageFragment.newInstance(nameImage);
                        imageMessageFragment.show(fm, null);
                    }
                });
            } else if (!msg.getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && msg.isImage()) {
                getImageStorage(holder.imageViewMessageFriend, msg.getUidSender(), msg.getUidReceiver(), msg.getContent());
                holder.imageViewMessageFriendTime.setText(msg.getTimeMessage().substring(11, 16));
                final String nameImage = msg.getContent();
                holder.imageViewMessageFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
                        ImageMessageFragment imageMessageFragment = ImageMessageFragment.newInstance(nameImage);
                        imageMessageFragment.show(fm, null);
                    }
                });
            } else if (msg.getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && msg.isAudio()) { // tin am thanh cua ban than
                holder.textViewMessageTimeAudioMine.setText(msg.getTimeMessage().substring(11, 16));
                holder.btnPlayAudioMessageMine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onPlayPressed(holder.btnPlayAudioMessageMine,msg.getUidSender(),
                                msg.getUidReceiver(),msg.getContent());
                    }
                });
            } else if (!msg.getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && msg.isAudio()) { // tin am thanh cua ban
                holder.textViewMessageTimeAudioFriend.setText(msg.getTimeMessage().substring(11, 16));
                holder.btnPlayAudioMessageFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onPlayPressed(holder.btnPlayAudioMessageFriend,msg.getUidSender(),
                                msg.getUidReceiver(),msg.getContent());
                    }
                });
            }

             //If the message itself and the message location last
            if(msg.getUidSender().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && (position == (listMessages.size() - 1))){
                if(msg.isLastMessageSeen() && !msg.isAudio() && !msg.isAudio()){
                    getAvatarSeen(holder.avatarSeen,listMessages.get(listMessages.size() - 1).getUidReceiver());
                    holder.avatarSeen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else if(msg.isLastMessageSeen() && msg.isImage()){
                    getAvatarSeen(holder.avatarSeenImage,listMessages.get(listMessages.size() - 1).getUidReceiver());
                    holder.avatarSeenImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else if(msg.isLastMessageSeen() && msg.isAudio()){
                    getAvatarSeen(holder.avatarSeenAudio,listMessages.get(listMessages.size() - 1).getUidReceiver());
                    holder.avatarSeenAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost 250 lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> storageReference.child(key).remove();

Did you tried that?